# SerialDataReceived Event Problems

Tags: c#, wpf

So I already solved my Arduino sending to my GUI problem (actively received). But sad to say there's another problem pops up. I can't update my GUI using my GUI's functions like Disabler() ->> which will disable the buttons.

So here is my sample code.

For my Data Received Event

```
private void Senport_DataReceived(Object sender, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
    {
        SerialPort Senport = (SerialPort)sender;
        rdata = Senport.ReadLine();
        ShowWindow();
    }
```

For my Show Window Function

```
public void ShowWindow()
    {

        if(rdata.Contains("FEED")==true)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Feeds already being dispense!","Feeding Process",MessageBoxButton.OK,MessageBoxImage.Information);

        }
        else if(rdata.Contains("DRINK")==true)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Drinkable water already being dispense!", "Drinking Water Process",MessageBoxButton.OK,MessageBoxImage.Information);

        }
        else if(rdata.Contains("CLEAN")==true)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Cleaning the cage is done!", "Cleaning Process",MessageBoxButton.OK,MessageBoxImage.Information);

        }

        else if(rdata.Contains("Fsms")==true)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Feeds Dispensing is starting","Drinking Water Process",MessageBoxButton.OK,MessageBoxImage.Information);
        }

        else if(rdata.Contains("Dsms")==true)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Water Dispensing is starting", "Drinking Water Process",MessageBoxButton.OK,MessageBoxImage.Information);

        }

        else if(rdata.Contains("Csms")==true)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Cleaning Process is starting", "Cleaning Process",MessageBoxButton.OK,MessageBoxImage.Information);

        }
    }
```

But I wanted to use this function below but an exception error will pop up.

```
  public void Disabler()
    {
        switch(flagger)
        {
            case 1: FEED.IsEnabled=false; FEED2.IsEnabled=false; Clean.IsEnabled=false; break;
            case 2: Clean.IsEnabled=false; FEED.IsEnabled=false; FEED2.IsEnabled=false; break;
            case 3: Clean.IsEnabled=false; FEED.IsEnabled=false; FEED2.IsEnabled=false; break;
        }
    }
```

So how can I use this function? By the way the error says that this function is not on the same thread. Hope you can help me :D Thanks!

Comment: "exception error will pop up" what exception or error you are seeing ? What is the functionality performed by Disbler method ? Where "FEED", "FEED2", "Clean" etc. are declared?

Comment: It say I can use it because it is in another thread. The function of Disabler() is to disable the buttons for how many seconds or hours. So Yeah i describe it above.

Comment: Got it... How and where are you calling Disabler() method? can you explain the use case  or functionality which you are trying to achieve?

Comment: Ill put it under the ShowWindow() function. The functionality I want to achieve is to disable the buttons when rdata will received "Fsms" code or "Csms" which a code that is send via SMS thru the GSM module.

Answer (score 0):

[image]
So this is the exception error that will appear. When im trying to put the function Disabler(); inside in every if statement of the function ShowWindow();